# Two DataSets in the same Tablix

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have one DataSet with a few fields, and a DataSet associated to one of the fields:

```
DataSet Workers {
    WorkerID
    WorkerName
    ...
    Tasks [1 ~ N DataTask]
}
```

.

```
DataSet Task {
    TaskID
    TaskName
    TaskTime
    TaskWorker
}
```

In my ReportViewer, I've put a list grouped by Worker and inside each element, a table that display Worker Data and a group of Tasks he's assigned to.

```
Row:[ TableLine: [WorkerID1 | WorkerName | etc] <- Rows grouped by Worker 
      TableLine: [TaskID1   | TaskName   | etc] <- TableLines grouped by Tasks
      TableLine: [TaskID2   | TaskName   | etc]
      TableLine: [TaskID3   | TaskName   | etc]
    ]
Row:[ TableLine: [WorkerID2 | etc...
```

The problem is that the ReportViewer doesn't allow me to group by "Task" inside the table, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I thin you can't use two datasets, however, if you are using a sql database, you can create a view with two tables and use it as a dataset

Comment: I'm not using sql, but I already solved the problem by using join(LookupSet()) function. Thanks!